# Jquery click div inside div using on

Tags: jquery

I would like to click divs inside an #TAGS1

```
$(document).on('click','div > #TAGS1',function(){alert('go crazy');});
```

I tried a variety of things but I cannot seem to make it work. I would like to use .on.

Comment: Why `.on()` vs `.click()`? Are your divs added dynamically?

Comment: Yes they are added dynamically

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#TAGS1 div').on('click',function(){alert('go crazy');});
```

Comment: I need to use $(document) because in my case, TAGS1 is loaded onto the page. Without $(document) it will otherwise not pick up the new added TAGS1

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#TAGS1 > div',function(){
        alert('go crazy');
    });
</script>

<div id="TAGS1">
  <div>Text 1</div>
  <div>Text 2</div>
  <div>Text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I had it backwards. appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If you have an element with #TAGS1 and you want handle clicks on every div inside of that element than this should work for you.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns2z8/)

```
<section id="TAGS1">
    <span>span1</span>
    <div>div1</div>
     <div>div2</div>
      <span>span2</span>
</section>



 $(document).on('click','#TAGS1 div',function(){alert('go crazy');});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#TAGS1 div").click(function() {
    alert('go crazy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery method [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is an shortcut to the click event for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), changing your event binding to:

```
$('#TAGS1 div').click(function(e){
  alert('go crazy');
});
```

Should achieve what you want.

If you really want to use `.on()` you can do so using the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#TAGS1 div', function(e) {
  alert('go crazy');
});
```

Answer (score -3):

the hell?

provide your jquery version next time...

Anyways.
your outdated code resembles this of updated and more preferred code.

```
$("div > #TAGS1").click(function(e){
     alert("clicked");
});
```

if your code is not working still, then you have an issue with your html.
div > #tags1 is saying.. Tags1 is a child of division. make sure that is true in your html.

Comment: `$("div > #TAGS1").click(` will add a handler to all matching tags _when that code runs_, `$(document).on('click','div > #TAGS1',` will bind the click handler to document, and act only on elements matching `div > #TAGS1`. This is known as event delegation and as [jQuery's docs put it](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): `Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.` -1 for tone.